# Filtering Data on Array Condition and putting over on each other(Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets

Actually I am trying to Filter the data using query and than result should use to get the data from another table and final result should stack up into one table.

Currently I am using this formula :-

> =arrayformula(query({arrayformula(query({A3:A10,B3:C10},"Select * where Col1 contains  '"& arrayformula(QUERY({E3:E7,F3:F7},"Select Col1 where Col2 = 'Yes'",0))&"'"))},"Select * ",0))

You'll understand by example, if you follow this sheet :-  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m1zC1wIM7GXWzCXz0i-B-2Q4xaBTctAATz6qfZg9J9A/edit#gid=0

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the second tab, I entered in cell A1

```
=query(Data!A3:C10, "where A matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, FILTER(Data!E3:E5,Data!F3:F5="Yes"))&"'", 0)
```

See if that works for you?